# Does artifactory support access token exchange?

Tags: artifactory, federation

We have multiple different identity providers federated (ADFS, GitHub, OpenID) with our identity management system. It won't work for us to recreate all the identity management federations with Artifactory in order for us to distribute artifacts in a protected manner. Is there any ability for Artifactory to do a token exchange similar to AWS.Cognito that can then be used to access Artifactory programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can Authenticate users in Artifactory using external identity providers via several common protocols (LDAP, SAML, OAuth, CROWD...) - [read some examples here](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Authentication)

You will still have to define the Authorization (permissions) in Artifactory - Which Users/Groups can Read/Write/Manage etc which Resources (Repos)

To make your life easier, check out the Artifactory [Access Token](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Access+Tokens) page, to see if it answers your programmatically accessing of Artifactory.
Using Access Tokens you can grant scoped access to your artifactory resources without having to integrate external realm users into Artifactory.

HTH,

Comment: I read through the various examples around federation options. This is a little different in that I don't want to have to duplicate the federation that already exists with our primary application. I want Artifactory to do a token exchange from our primary application and have Artifactory take that user in the same way I do with AWS Cognito. My understanding with the Access Tokens is that you need to have the user already in created. I don't want Artifactory to care about the user as long as the user is authenticated already with our primary application.